# Como alterar o nome de um endpoint?

Tags: python, fastapi

Estou usando o FastAPI e meu endpoint esta assim:

```py
@router.get(
    "/teste",
    include_in_schema=True,
    response_model=model_res.TRetRecepcaoLeitura,
    response_description="Resposta do ONE para recepcao da leitura",
    description="Procedimento de recepcão de leituras no ONE."
)
def receber_as_leitura_dos_equipamentos_teste(recepcao: model_rec.TRecepLeitura):
    return (recepcao)
```

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Quando eu olho a documentação, o nome do endpoint está baseado no nome da função. Como faço para ele mostrar um nome baseado em uma string ao invés do nome da função?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o atributo `name`:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/", name="Nome que será exibido")
async def using_name_attr():
    """Descrição do endpoint."""
    return {}
```

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>